# get usable space of internal storage android

Tags: java, android, textview, directory

How to get the usable space of the internal storage of the android, for example a folder of Photos or Download ... being more specific, I need to access a folder of the gallery that is created by another Application in the case is the WhatsApp photos folder. I'm new to the Android mobile developer, and the company is asking this as a challenge. I saw some technologies but they only say how to do to SD Card and I do not know how I can apply for INTERNAL mode. Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

```
File [] externalStorageFiles = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs (this, null);

            / **
             * We get the external directory
             * /
             File externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ();

          

            / **
             * We take the folder (Here you must enter the path you want)
             * /
             File downloadFolder = new File (externalStorageDirectory.getAbsolutePath () + "/ Download");


            / **
             * If directory exists
             * /
            If (downloadFolder.exists ()) {

                / **
                 * Messages with folder information
                 * /

                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), downloadFolder.getUsableSpace () + "bytes used", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();
                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), downloadFolder.getFreeSpace () + "free bytes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();
                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), downloadFolder.getTotalSpace () + "total bytes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();

                If (null! = Folder.listFiles ()) {
                    Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), folder.listFiles (). Length + "files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();
                }

            } Else {
                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "Directory does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();

            }
```

Comment: `access a folder of the gallery`. The 'gallery' is no storage location. But just an app that can show photos on your device. Please rephrase your need.

Comment: In case it would not access the Gallery, but access some internal folder of photos, for example access the size of the folder of images of whatsapp

Comment: Free space of folders does not exist. There is only free space of storage volumes. Please show the code you used for 'sd card'.

Comment: Sorry, in fact it is not free space, it is the space used in a particular folder in the internal storage. Okay, code follows below

Comment: You should edit your post to make it clear what you want. Where you are after. Free space or occupied space.

Comment: Now that you've managed to make a correct one

Comment: Again: there is no such thing as free space of a folder. And why did you mention `space used in a particular folder` as that is something which indeed you can determine easily.

Comment: `Thank you in advance.`. Can you remove that?